# Find all in-page urls that are same as window url

Tags: javascript

Is there anyway to detect all the links within a page that's the same as the window URL? Basically I have a left navigation and body navigation which when on that page, they have an active class bound to them both - so the user knows they're on that page. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean links that either match the domain of the page, or that are relative to the domain?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `a[href="+window.location.href+"` is your friend

Comment: Relevant as it'll be something like ?id=89 or something similar. How does that then bind all links to the window location?

Answer (score 2):

Use a CSS selector for `a` tags with specified `href` attribute:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='" + window.location.href + "']");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JQuery quite easily:

```
var linksWithSameUrl = $("a[href='" + window.location.href + "']")

var linksWithSameDomain = $("a[href^='" + window.location.host + "']")
```

Comment: OP does not label question as jQuery, so it's not an answer. Provide selector in pure JS